# Why is my initWithNibName method returning a nil view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xib, presentviewcontroller

I'm calling this method when trying to present a new view controller. The commented out lines are the other things I've tried with no success.

```
-(void)presentMailBoxViewController{
    TPMailBoxViewController* mailBoxViewController=[[TPMailBoxViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TPMailBoxViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mailBoxViewController animated:YES];
    //[self.navigationController presentViewController:mailBoxViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    //[self presentViewController:mailBoxViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

I've set the file owner as my corresponding view controller.

[image]

I've even linked the view object of my xib into my view controller as a property.

[image]

But, when I break on         `[self.navigationController pushViewController:mailBoxViewController animated:YES];`

The view property of the view controller is nil. What gives?

Comment: You use nibs or storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A project clean and this one line change in my presentMailBoxViewController fixed my issue. Still would like to know why though. Thanks everyone!

```
-(void)presentMailBoxViewController{
    TPMailBoxViewController* mailBoxViewController=[[TPMailBoxViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TPMailBoxViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:mailBoxViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"`UIViewController`" already has a "`view`" property, so you don't need "`myView`".

Open up your storyboard or XIB file and make certain that the "`view`" that you want to be displayed with your is connected in your storyboard or XIB file to your TPMailBoxViewController object.

Right after you "`initWithNibName`", the view controller object exists but its "`view`" property is likely to be nil because the view has not been loaded yet.

It's when you *push* the view controller, that is when your "`TPMailBoxViewController`" will get the "`viewWillLoad`" and "`viewWillAppear`" methods being called and when the view is loaded, the "`view`" outlet will change from `nil` to something real.

Comment: I don't understand, I don't need the myView property... but you're also telling me to link my xib's root view object to my view controller... isn't that what I'm already doing with "myView"???

Comment: I see your edit, after I push the view controller, viewDidAppear is never called.

Comment: "`UIViewController`" has a "`view`" property for the view that the view controller owns. Make sure that the UIViewController `view` outlet is connected to the view in your XIB or storyboard file.

Comment: Yes of course, I only linked my xib's root view because that's what I had read in other solutions to this problem, it didn't seem necessary to me, and didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Those methods are called automatically.  Does your view appear?

Comment: Nope! That's my whole problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate, you need to set the root object of the window as the navigation controller. You can do it like this:-

```
YourViewController *rootObj = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
 UINavigationController *navObj = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootObj];

[self.window setRootViewController:navObj];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

After this, try pushing the viewcontroller, it should work